# Is there a way to make IntelliJ IDEA *not* put Scala source files in their Java-style package directory?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In Java, you have to put source files in the directory structure corresponding to their package.   foo.bar.Baz has to live in foo/bar/Baz.java.

In Scala, that requirement is relaxed.  If all your classes in a particular project are in package foo.bar, you might just want them to live in the root source directory.

But IDEA flags this as an error, and forces me to put Scala classes in their Java-style directory when, for example, I copy or move classes.  Is there a way to turn off this behavior?

Comment: If you mean the .class files output when it compiles, no, the JVM dictates that.

Comment: No, I mean the source directory.

Comment: Scala allows it, but IDEA prefers that you not do it, for what I gather are performance reasons. I'm just so happy to be free of the "one public class per source file" restriction of Java that I don't care about mirroring the package structure in the directory structure. In fact, I never objected to that part, even though it's not technically required by the Java language, either. … Anyway, why don't you want to conform to this stricture?

Comment: It just feels less crufty to have a shallower tree.  I'd agree that one-class-per-file is a bigger win.

Answer (score 0):

Go Settings -> Scala -> Other settings -> Resolve to all classes, even in wrong directories.

Comment: Alefas, that doesn't seem to change the behavior of the copy/move dialogs.  They still insist on putting source files in the package-path