# How to stop IntelliJ Idea from changing package declarations when moving or copying Scala files

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, directory, package

Unlike Java, Scala does not require the location of a file to correspond to the file's package declaration - e.g. a file in the package `com.company.project` need not be in `com/company/project`. My company's Scala projects have a directory structure that does not correspond to their package structure, and the Scala compiler is quite happy with this.

However, when moving or copying a Scala file, IntelliJ automatically changes the file's package declaration to match its location. To work around this, I have to either manually revert the change or use a separate tool to do these file operations.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896337/is-there-a-way-to-make-intellij-idea-not-put-scala-source-files-in-their-java) is related but doesn't describe the exact behaviour I'm talking about.)

Comment: I doubt it.  That behavior is deeply embedded in Java; I don't think it's possible to disable it by language.

Comment: @duffymo As I mentioned in the question, Scala itself has no problem with a directory structure that doesn't match the package structure - this is purely an IDE issue. I've edited the question to emphasize this more.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  I agree: I believe it is an IDE issue.  The "J" in "IntelliJ" means "Java".  While the JetBrains folks are incredibly smart, I would be surprised if their IDE could say "If it's Java, do this; Scala do that."  Maybe a better place to ask would be the JetBrains community support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. A request for this feature has been opened on JetBrains YouTrack [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10010).